# javascript recursive function concat not working

Tags: javascript

I have a nested array of objects like below and I'm trying to push all the values in to a single array. all the values are located in `sp->it->value` or `sp->it->it->value`

```
[
{
    "sp": [
            {
              "it":[
                    {"value":5}
               ]
            },
            ...
        ],
    "b": {
        ...
    }
},
{
    "sp": [
            {
              "it":[
                {"nm":5}
                ]
            }
        ],
    "b": {
        ...
    }
},
{
    "sp": [
            {
              "it":[
                {
                  "it":[
                    {"value":5}
                  ]
                }
               ]
           }
        ],
    "b": {
        ...
    }
},

]
```

and here is what I have tried

```
const getValues = (js) => {
    let values = []
    js.map((val,i) => {
        if("sp" in val) values.concat(getValues(val.sp))
        else if("it" in val) values.concat(getValues(val.it))
         else if("value" in val) values.push(val.value)
    })
    return values
}
```

I thought I could concatenate the returned value from the recursive call since it returns an array but the above code returns empty array. Any insights?

**Edit** fixed the typo on sp object. It is array of objects.

Comment: `map` returns an array. If you're not going to use the return value, use `forEach`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey it was a typo. fixed it

Comment: You didn't fix anything related to my comment. You're still using `map` for side effects instead of using it for its return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method **does not change the existing arrays**, but instead returns a new array.

So those lines do nothing:

```
if("sp" in val) values.concat(getValues(val.sp))
else if("it" in val) values.concat(getValues(val.it))
```

You need to write:

```
if("sp" in val) values = values.concat(getValues(val.sp))
else if("it" in val) values = values.concat(getValues(val.it))
```

And you should not use `map` if you don't use it's result. Use `forEach` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are passing `val.sp` to function which is not array but it is an object and .map is a property of an array